# The Bug genie mercurial integration under windows

Tags: python, mercurial-hook

I'm struggling to get the mercurial hook script for The Bug Genie working under windows, it can be found here : [TheBugGenie:Addons:VCSMercurial](http://issues.thebuggenie.com/wiki/TheBugGenie:Addons:VCSMercurial)

The hook seems to fire but the command prompt rapidly disappears with the error message (probably) in it.

I've never done python, but I've tried adding some code like

```
os.system('ipconfig > F:\\xyz')
```

to test if the code is actually running, with no success.

Can I get some help?

Comment: `'ipconfig > F:\xyz'` won't work because `\x` starts an escape escape sequence and `yz` isn't a valid hex value, therefore the script won't run because this will cause an error while parsing the script. You need to either escape backslashes by doubling them, or use a raw string (`r'...'`).

Comment: I actually fixed that, but with no success.

Comment: have you tried using `hg` directly from cmd to see the actual error message? Other then that, there may be an issue with your configuration, you should consider posting the relevant parts of your repo/global mercurial config.